# How to get a list of Globalized fields in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize

I use gems `globalize` and `globalize_accessors` for translating my models. Here is an example:

```
# model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :title, :description
  globalize_accessors
end
```

I want to be able to retreive the list of fields i.e. `[:title, :description]` in the form to loop over them.

I have poked around and the only thing I could find was `#globalize_attribute_names` method. However it returns a list of translated fields with locales ordered by original title:

```
[:title_en, :title_es, :title_xx, :description_en, ... ]
```

So, the question is - is there a way to get the list of fields I have specified in `translates` ?

I kind of fixed it like this, but it is not very nice:

```
  def translates
    globalize_attribute_names.map do |name|
      name[/(\w+)_\w{2}\z/]
      Regexp.last_match[1]
    end.uniq
  end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it was:

```
#translated_attribute_names
```